# Navigate to three pages in parallel with Selenium, ChromeDriver, and NUnit

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, google-chrome, nunit

As an experiment, I've created an NUnit test project that should, when running all tests, open three browser windows simultaneously, and each should load a particular page before closing.

My question is:  Am I using the WebDriver and ChromeDriver APIs correctly, especially with regard to best practices?

First, I created an assembly-level SetUpFixture.  This creates a ChromeDriverService to be shared between `IWebDriver` instances.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

[SetUpFixture]
public class AssemblySetup
{
    private static ChromeDriverService _chromeDriverService;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public static void OneTimeSetUp()
    {
        _chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        _chromeDriverService.Start();
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public static void OneTimeTearDown()
    {
        _chromeDriverService.Dispose();
    }

    public static ChromeDriverService ChromeDriverService
    {
        get { return _chromeDriverService; }
    }
}
```

Then I created a `TestBase` to encapsulate the `IWebDriver` set-up and teardown:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;

namespace SeleniumSandbox
{
    public abstract class TestBase
    {
        private IWebDriver _webDriver;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(AssemblySetup.ChromeDriverService.ServiceUrl, DesiredCapabilities.Chrome());
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            _webDriver.Quit();
        }

        public IWebDriver WebDriver
        {
            get { return _webDriver; }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I created the three tests:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace SeleniumSandbox
{
    [TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable]
    public class TestA : TestBase
    {
        [Test]
        public void Run()
        {
            WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.microsoft.com");
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable]
    public class TestsB : TestBase
    {
        [Test]
        public void Run()
        {
            WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable]
    public class TestsC : TestBase
    {
        [Test]
        public void Run()
        {
            WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.amazon.com");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm concerned that I've deviated from the examples I've found.  For example, I'm not using `ChromeDriverService` like the example under "Controlling ChromeDriver's lifetime" [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started).  I also deviated from the many examples I can find, in which people instantiate IWebDriver with `new ChromeDriver(service, options)`, because doing so caused additional ChromeDriver instances to start with port-related error messages.

Comment: What are the actual tests? This seems more like a test setup, and if so do you want us to review the test setup?

Comment: Yes, it's the setup, and in particular the usage of ChromeDriverService with RemoteWebDriver, that I'd like to get feedback on.  The actual tests aren't of consequence.